# Razor Pages Trying to create a custom audio player in the shared footer and multiple icons appear when only specifying one icon using FontAwesome cdn

Tags: icons, razor-pages, audio-player

In my razor page project, I am trying to create an audio player using html and javascript, and decided to put the audio player in the footer shared by all razor pages. When I was adding an icon, multiple of them showed up in the wrong area.

Here is the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Player.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Player</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div id="audio-container">
            <i class="fas fa-backward"</i>
            
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

When I was expecting only one icon to show in the footer several of them appeared, and not in the footer

[Resulting Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGyo6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Realized that I was missing a closing icon tag <i class="fas fa-backward" should be